# Prove Σ* is decidable

Tags: computability

I see that Σ* is claimed to be decidable in many documents, but I have never seen an example or easy demostration that it is decidable.

What is the proof that Σ* is decidable?

Comment: This is a very trivial question. What words are in $\Sigma^*$? What words are *not* in $\Sigma^*$ (if any)? So how would you write a decider for $\Sigma^*$?

Comment: The definition of decidability pretty much answers the question. (At least after reading Hoopje's comment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem:** *The set $\Sigma^{*}$ of all words is decidable.*

*Proof.* According to the definition of decidability, we must provide a computable function $d$ which takes a word $w$ and outputs $1$ if $w \in \Sigma^{*}$, and outputs $0$ if $w \not\in \Sigma^{*}$. Such a function is very easily constructed, it is
$$d(w) = 1,$$
That is, because every word is in $\Sigma^{*}$, the decision function always says "yes". QED.